# Using htaccess for pretty URLs with and without trailing slash?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here's my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

This code works for this URL:

```
https://example.com/test-page
```

But it doesn't work for this:

```
https://example.com/test-page/
```

Is there a way to make it work for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two separate rules for this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```